# A more efficient way to store data in MySQL using more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I had one single table that had lots of problems. I was saving data separated by commas in some fields, and afterwards I wasn't able to search them. Then, after search the web and find a lot of solutions, I decided to separate some tables.

That one table I had, became 5 tables.

First table is called agendamentos_diarios, this is the table that I'm gonna be storing the schedules.

Second Table is the table is called tecnicos, and I'm storing the technicians names. Two fields, id (primary key) and the name (varchar).

Third table is called agendamento_tecnico. This is the table (link) I'm goona store the id of the first and the second table. Thats because there are some schedules that are gonna be attended by one or more technicians.

Forth table is called veiculos (vehicles). The id and the name of the vehicle (two fields).

Fith table is the link between the first and the vehicles table. Same thing. I'm gonna store the schedule id and the vehicle id.

I had an image that can explain better than I'm trying to say.

[image: Diagram]

Am I doing it correctly? Is there a better way of storing data to MySQL?

Comment: This isn't lots of tables ;-). Have you studied basic normalisation rules? Check out http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/ for an introduction. Just keep digging.

Comment: Yes - although the id columns in your linking tables are probably redundant.

Comment: I suggest to rename the question; 5 tables are not lots - it's a bit missleading - how about spread data over some tables, or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Strawberry about the ids, but normally it is the Hibernate mapping type that do this. If you are not using Hibernate to design your tables you should take the ID out from agendamento_tecnico and agendamento_veiculos. That way you garantee the unicity. If you don't wanna do that create a unique key on the FK fields on thoose tables.

I notice that you separate the vehicles table from your technicians. On your model the same vehicle can be in two different schedules at the same time (which doesn't make sense). It will be better if the vehicle was linked on agendamento_tecnico table which will turn to be agendamento_tecnico_veiculo.

Looking to your table I note (i'm brazilian) that you have a column called "servico" which, means service. Your schedule table is designed to only one service. What about on the same schedule you have more than one service? To solve this you can create a table services and create a m-n relationship with schedule. It will be easier to create some reports and have the services well separated on your database.

There is also a nome_cliente field which means the client for that schedule. It would be better if you have a cliente (client) table and link the schedule with an FK.

As said before, there is no right answer. You have to think about your problem and on the possible growing of it. Model a database properly will avoid lot of headache later.

Comment: Oh, understanding the language, helps, I have overseen this (probably) wrong N:M between vehicle and schedules

Answer (score 2):

Better is subjective, there's no right answer.

My natural instinct would be to break that schedule table up even more.
Looks like data about the technician and the client is duplicated.

There again you might have made a decisions to de-normalise for perfectly valid reasons.

Doubt you'll find anyone on here who disagrees with you not having comma separated fields though.

Where you call a halt to the changes is dependant on your circumstances now. Comma separated fields caused you an issue, you got rid of them. So what bit of where you are is causing you an issue now?

Answer (score 1):

looks ok, especially if a first try

one comment: *I* would name PK/FK (ids) the same in all tables and not using 'id' as name (additionaly we use '#' or '_' as end char of primary / foreighn keys: example `technicos.technico_` and `agendamento_tecnico` has fields `agend_tech_` and `technico_`. But this is not common sense. It makes queries a bit more coplex (because you must fully qualify the fields), but make the databse schema mor readable (you know in the moment wich PK belong to wich FK)

other comment: the two assotiative (i never wrote that word before!)  tables, joining `technos` and `agendamento_tecnico` have an own ID field, but they do not need that, because the two (primary/unique) keys of the two tables they join, are unique them selfes, so you can use them as PK for this tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE agendamento_tecnico (
    technico_ int not null,
    agend_tech_ int not null,
    primary key(technico_,agend_tech_)
)
```

Comment: Don't know whether the id key in the joins is needed, but they certainly don't appear to be used.